# How to display default image if the category row is null

Tags: php

if user have no image and category is null in our database then row show default photo. and also i need 4 image in each category..
how can i do this please help me thanks

```
 // Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,
 $password, $dbname); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 


     $sql_pro = "SELECT imgname from providers where categories = 'Diet and Fitness' ";

     $run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_pro);//here run the sql query.  
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  

        $imgname = $row[0];
     $categories="Diet and Fitness";

     if($categories=='null')
     {
        echo "<img src='images/default.png'  width='139px' height='100px'>";
         }
     else
     {
         echo " <img src='uploads/providers/$imgname' width='139px' height='100px'>";  
     }


 $conn->close(); } ?>
```

Comment: how the category will be null if you are assigning it staticly

Comment: i have a different categories and i want to show 4 images in each category but if there is no image in database and category is empty it will show default image

Comment: try like `if($categories=='null' || $imgname == '' || $imgname == NULL)`

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya what should i have to do now

Comment: try the code given by @Sinto

Comment: it shows images not default image

Comment: So you have a image for "Diet and Fitness" category. Can you add output of `print_r($row[0]);`. If you have given `$categories="Diet and Fitness";` , then there is no need of having the condition as `if($categories=='null')`

Comment: Where are you getting `Diet and Fitness` category name? Is it coming from the request or it is hardcoded?

Comment: @Sinto yes i have a images for different category  and i want when the  user enter the   data through form then it will show image otherwise show default image

Comment: its coming from the database and i take it from user through form as a drop down box and it saves in to my providers table

Comment: `$categories=='null'` checks if your `$categories` is a string with a value of `"null"`, which it probably isn't. Use `!isset()` or `empty()` to check if `$categories` is empty. And remember to remove `$categories="Diet and Fitness";` beforehand.

Comment: $sql_pro = "SELECT imgname from providers where categories = 'Diet and Fitness' ";
        
        $run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_pro);//here run the sql query.  
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        
           $imgname = $row[0];
       
      if($categories=='null')
        {
          echo "<img src='images/default.png'  width='139px' height='100px'>";
            }
        else
        {
       echo " <img src='uploads/providers/$imgname' width='139px' height='100px'>";  
        }

Comment: still its not showing the default image

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

- First, you need to make category name dynamic as it is supposed to come from `request-data` through a form submitted by the user.
- Second, you need to change `if` condition to check `$imagename` variable whether it has any value or not which will decide whether to show the actual image from DB or a default image.

Here is how it will look like:

```
    <?php
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // Assuming Categoty name provided from request-data as user is 
    // submitting a form and it is coming in "category_name" key.
    // If it is not there in request-data then set it to 
    // default value as "Diet and Fitness"
    $categories = (isset($_REQUEST['category_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['category_name'])) ? $_REQUEST['category_name'] : 'Diet and Fitness';

    // Use "$categories" set above instead of hardcoded category name
    $sql_pro = "SELECT imgname from providers where categories = '" . $categories . "'";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_pro); //here run the sql query.

    // Just a guess if mysqli_num_rows() will provide us total number 
    // of rows in resultset. Please correct this function if not 
    // returning total row count.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
            //while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
            $imgname = $row[0];

            // This is not required now as we have category name 
            // in "$categories" variable.
            //$categories="Diet and Fitness";

            // Check if "imagename" is empty in database then use a 
            // default image otherwise use what is coming from DB.
            if($imgname == null OR $imgname == '') {
                echo "<img src='images/default.png'  width='139px' height='100px'>";
            } else {
                echo " <img src='uploads/providers/$imgname' width='139px' height='100px'>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "<img src='images/default.png'  width='139px' height='100px'>";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Because images of a category are coming from the database table called `providers` so `while` loop will automatically show as many images as much you have in the table.

Comment: still not showing default image it just shows the images present in DB

Comment: Then put entire `while` loop in an `if` checking whether it has any row in DB `else` show a default image. Code modified.